# Trigger garbage collection to measure performance of a webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, garbage-collection

Is there a reliable (and considerably simple) way to create enough load to trigger GC so I can properly analyze the performance of Tomcat?
I have looked into Selenium and JMeter and found the first not suitable and the second way too complicated and overloaded for my purpose.

Comment: And what is hosted on your Tomcat? A REST application, a Web application, ...?

Comment: A webapp, forgot to mention

Comment: Would be better if you would edit the question and put it there... that this is for a web app...

Comment: Just to monitor java params you could use console as well ...

Comment: *Is there a reliable (and considerably simple) way to create enough load to trigger GC?* No.

Comment: Is there a reliable and considerably simple method to test performance of a webapp, if not by looking at GC times then?

Comment: GC is not a measure of performance.  It may hinder performance, but it is not the key metric.  You need to understand what the performance metrics are that you care about before investigating any tool indepth.  The usual metrics are number of requests per second, latency and so forth.

Comment: This wikipedia page may help you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing

Answer (score 1):

[Gatling](http://gatling.io/) is an excellent load testing tool, I would not go back to JMeter.